# Cannot assign to 'xxx' in 'self'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6-beta6

I got this compiler error: *Cannot assign to 'sci' in 'self'*

```
class LCCVC: UICollectionViewCell {

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)

        sci = nil
    }
}
```

sci is a global variable declared in an other file like this:

```
var sci: NSManagedObject?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a method called `sci()` in that class, that caused the compiler error.